# Assign java scripts to cloned HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html div and I clone it using Jquery. That div contains labels and text fields. ids of all of them generated and assigned dynamically. I have no problem with that.
A java script is assigned to a text field of original div. The cloned text fields does not have the javascript assigned to it.

**the script I need to assign:**

```
<script>
            $(function() {
                $("#datepick_onBooking,#datepick_Pay1,#datepick_Pay2,#datepick_totPay,#datepick_deedFees").datepicker();
            });
        </script>
```

**the script I use to make clones:**

```
<script>

            var i = 3;
            //When DOM loaded we attach click event to button
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#addAnotherPayment').click(function() {

                    var cloned = $('.PayDiv0').first().clone();
                    var noOfDivs = $('.PayDiv0').length+2;
                    cloned.insertBefore("#totPayForm");

                    // append count to the ids
                    cloned.attr('id', 'PayDiv' + noOfDivs);
                    cloned.find('label').attr('id', 'PayLbl' + noOfDivs);
                    cloned.find('input[type="text"]').attr('id', 'datepick_Pay'+ noOfDivs);
                    cloned.find('input[type="number"]').attr('id', 'amount_Pay'+ noOfDivs);

                    cloned.find('.PayLbl2').html("Payment No " + i++ + ':');
                });

            });
        </script>
```

`datepick_Pay1, datepick_Pay2, datepick_totPay, datepick_deedFees` are static elements and they have been assigned to the script. I create text fields using cloning as `datepick_Pay3,datepick_Pay4`, and so on.

I cannot figure out how to dynamically assign the script to that newly created elements.How can I do that?

Comment: Look into delegated events http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data should be copied along with the elements.
change this line.

var cloned = $('.PayDiv0').first().clone(true);

Answer (score 1):

when you clone something especially elements which having events 
use parameter as 
clone(true)

But this will be harmfull based on how event is attached on the actual element when copying the events to the cloned element may affect the actual.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone with events. http://api.jquery.com/clone/

> var cloned = $('.PayDiv0').first().clone(**true**);

Then your script needs to be changed to work for dynamic elements. Here as soon as input elements gets focus, asssign the datepicker based on wild card id selector, if it doesn't already have one.

```
 $(function() {
            $('body').on('focus',"input[id^=datepick_]", function(){
                if(!$(this).hasClass('.hasdatepicker'))
                {
                 $(this).datepicker();
                }
            });      
});
```